# How to add all of the websites Google has indexed to a Google Custom Search

Tags: html, google-search, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I want to add all of the websites indexed by Google in a Google custom search. If I try to add sites manually from the Google custom search, it would take more than my life to include all of them.Is there any way I can do that with any trick? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? Is your goal to simply embed a Google search in one of your pages?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel: Yes. I want to embed complete Google search into my site and monetize it with them.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that there is a solution to your question. Here is why:

Google provides their search tool in order to enable people to search their own site and a list of relevant sites of their choosing. However, if Google allowed you to use their entire search tool in your site then there would be no reason to visit Google anymore, thus their advertising revenue would plummet.

One of the things you could consider is choosing the sites that you want to add and then creating a script that will automatically add more sites based on what your users search for.

Comment: Every 1000 queries cost 5$ and there is upper limit, so IMHO advertising revenue is not a reason here for disabling all site search.

Answer (score 1):

Where it says: Sites to search, don't go into the submenus for adding specific sites. There is a dropdown off to the side that will change from "Search Only Included Sites" to "Search Entire Web but emphasize included sites"

[image: Search Entire Web]

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

http://www.google.com/cse/

Comment: I am using it. The thing is that asks you to enter the sites you want to search in. How do I add of the sites indexed by Google in it?

Comment: from what i've read the option to search all of google will appear on your search results page once you place it on your site.

Answer (score 0):

According to google, all web search is not possible:
http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210656

However it is possible to include all know top-level domains to search engine.
Acording to:
http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70322
it would be like: *.com, *.ch, *.pl and many more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

More importantly, if google forbids to perform all web search then any hack won't last long.

Comment: I have heard that list of top-level domains will be in close future opened. Does somebody know more about it?